# How to practice when 2 customs collide

Tags: halacha, minhag, tznius-modesty, current-events

This question is inspired by recent news of events in Beit Shemesh.

What happens halachically when 2 customs collide and each custom affects the other side?  In the case of modesty, for example, requiring one side to dress more modestly may be a physical burden on that community.  Maintaining their present dress may spiritually affect the other community.

There are many opinions flying around about the present situation but I have heard little about the way such disputes should be handled or were handled historically.  I am looking for halachic sources and precedents only, but can be from any matter not just modesty.

Comment: I hate to say it but the Custom has always been amogst Jews no matter what country when 2 customs collide is to fight about it

Comment: And that's probably true despite halachic rulings otherwise.  I would still be interested in responsa on the subject.

Comment: Regarding the issue of dressing with tznuah... If you read the actual sources, they only talk about what a man is not allowed to look at.  The proper behavior as written "on the books" is to "close your eyes" or "look away", if their version of erva is not your version.

Comment: @avi, I would appreciate if you would bring those sources and post them as an answer.

Comment: @YDK, but.. that was only the prelude to your actual question :)

Comment: As a resident of Bet Shemesh, I would like to point out that the recent events have absolutely *nothing* to do with customs or halacha. It is solely and completely an issue of one not-so-small group trying to meticulously control everything about anyone else. I would think that their completely non-halachic actions would make that clear to anyone, even without having to delve into what they're actually *saying* - which, for the record, has even *less* to do with halacha.

Comment: @AviD, I can appreciate your feelings of being in the middle of a control issue.  Although my question was inspired by the events in Beit Shemesh (and much of it may border on lunacy), my real curiosity is when two communities with age old customs come together and one custom has serious effects on the other community.  This may have been in business practices as well.

Comment: @YDK thank you, I understand that you were not asking specifically about Bet Shemesh, I just wanted to make it clear. So, out of curiosity, how far has this news spread??

Answer (score 6):

Re what happens when two customs collide?

This is very important question.

The answer: in historic times, despite disagreements, the two camps would still be friends with each other and the followers would marry each other (the proof of real friendship).

Source: Beit Hillel and Beit Shammai would marry each other (despite their many disagreements on matters of Halacha). <strike>This is said specifically in the Gemara, but I don't have the source daf.</strike>

**Updated** source is a Beraisa on Yevamos 14. [A src.](http://www.shemayisrael.com/dafyomi2/yevamos/reviewa/ye-ra-014.htm)

See [many articles about this issue.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hillel%20shammai%20marry%20each%20other)

It is unfortunate that this principle is not more widely known or followed these days.

Comment: I was thinking about this gemara as I wrote the question, but from what I recall, they were careful not to violate those specifics that they argued about.

Comment: @YDK: indeed. The Gemara in fact entertains the idea that it was all a theoretical machlokes and that even Beis Shammai never followed their opinion in practice, though it also leaves open the possibility that they did and would just take care to inform each other of the specifics of each case so that no one would end up going against their own halachic opinion.

Comment: Be careful with this... this is only true when both sides were honestly seeking the truth. See, for example, the way perushim in the time frame of Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai responded to Tzedukim.